# JQuery check if link is clicked not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hyperlink

I have a bootstrap pagination. I want if a page was clicked just get a red background and stay. to show which page is currently active.
the problem is when the page reloads after clicking, the background doesn't remain and wanished.
how to fix this?

ps. this code works fine for other elements but links and buttons, means the problem is just reloading and I need reloading. I put an alert just for test in JS.

ps2. I don't want all links get background color after visiting, its pagination and only active page must get.

```js
$('.page-link').on('click',function (){
        alert('ok');
        $(this).addClass('active-page');
    })
```

```css
.active-page{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul class="pagination">
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=login">1</a></li>
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250210/discussion-on-question-by-unique631-jquery-check-if-link-is-clicked-not-working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Prev</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is your solution.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    let activePage = localStorage.getItem("activePage");

    if (activePage === "Prev") {
      $(".page-link").eq(0).addClass("active-page");
      localStorage.removeItem("activePage");
    } else if (activePage === "Next") {
      $(".page-link")
        .eq($(".page-link").length - 1)
        .addClass("active-page");
      localStorage.removeItem("activePage");
    } else if (activePage === null) {
    } else {
      $(".page-link").eq(activePage).addClass("active-page");
      localStorage.removeItem("activePage");
    }

    $(".page-link").on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass("active-page");
        localStorage.setItem("activePage", $(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to learn [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow. A code dump (even code that solve the OPs problem) with no explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: @Rafiul Islam Rafi This code works fine, but when I add two more links it doesn't, why?

Comment: I add two links, Previous and next. with same class of numbers links.

Comment: when page 1 is active, the previous link gets backcolor. and when number 2 is active, number 1 gets.

Comment: When you add prev and next button then you have to add if logic for this two button.

Comment: @RafiulIslamRafi ok.it fixed the problem.thanks, it will be good if you add explanation about the code you've written. its a bit hard to understand. but anyway its the answer and I mark it as answer.

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(() => {
let activePage = localStorage.getItem("activePage");

```
    if (activePage) {
      $(".page-link")
        .eq(activePage - 1)
        .addClass("active-page");
      localStorage.removeItem("activePage");
    }

    $(".page-link").on("click", function () {
      $(this).addClass("active-page");
      localStorage.setItem("activePage", $(this).text());
    });
```

});

Comment: Please take the time to learn [how to write a good answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). A simple code dump with no explanation is not a good answer.